# MySQL JDBC Statement Problems

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I can't for the life of me figure out why I keep getting this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) FROM login' at line 1
```

I've tried using ' around the table name, using ` ... nothing works.  I was able to execute the exact same SQL on the computer and it works, when the program goes to do it it fails.  I'm just checking to see if a table is empty (although I get the same error when I try to pull data from the table as well).  I've tried using (*) and * as well - still get the error.  Also tried with and without the ; - same result.

Code:

```
public boolean tableIsEmpty(String Table)
{
    String Query = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM "+Table+";";

    try{
        rs = st.executeQuery(Query);

        rs.next();

        int count = rs.getInt(1);

        if(count > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(DatabaseConnector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I remember having a similar problem before using postgresql but I added ' ' and it worked.  This is the first time I'm using MySQL through Java and can't figure this out.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to remove the space between the COUNT and the bracket. Not sure if that is the problem, though

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login;` [note the spaces, or lack thereof](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html)

Comment: Thanks guys that did it.  I never would have figured that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 String Query = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM "+Table+";";
```

Above should be

```
 String Query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "+Table;
                            ^^               ^^
                            ||               ||
                      //   space removed    ; removed
```